# ¿Cómo llenar un jComboBox con un ArrayList en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist, combobox

Primeramente lo que le solicito al usuario es que ingrese los datos para agregar un puesto, los cuales se extraen de los texfield y los envió por parametro para guardarlos en sus respectivos ArrayList, luego en el momento en el que deseo eliminar un puesto quiero llenar los jComboBox con los datos que ya están almacenados en los ArrayList.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String p = campoTexto1.getText();
    String s = campoTexto2.getText();
    String sa = campoTexto3.getText();
    pts.agregar_puestos(p, s, sa);

}
```

```
public class Puestos {

    public ArrayList<String> nombre = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList siglas = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList salario = new ArrayList<>();

    public void agregar_puestos(String p, String s, String sa) {

        nombre.add(p);
        siglas.add(s);
        salario.add(sa);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos Guardados Correctamente en el Sistema", "Exitoso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        System.out.print(nombre);
        System.out.print(siglas);
        System.out.print(salario);

    }


    public Eliminar_Puestos() {
        initComponents();
        llenarComboBox();
        
    }
    
    private void llenarComboBox(){
        ArrayList<String> nombre=pts.nombre;
        comboBox1.addItem(nombre);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que puedes hacer es trabajar directamente con el modelo, ejemplo:

Instancias un nuevo

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> modelo = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
```

A este modelo le agregas los elementos que quieres con

```
modelo.addElement("tu String");
```

después solo le agregas este modelo a tu combo, hay mas maneras pero esta se me hizo la mas sencilla y rápida.

La forma de darle el modelo seria.

```
JComboBox1.setModel(modelo);
```

Comment: entiendo, pero me gustaría saber si se podría llenar de igual forma mediante ese método con el ArrayList que ya tengo creado.

Comment: es que yo deseo según mi proyecto llenarlo con los datos que yo agrego en el ArrayList para despues esos mismo que yo agrego poder eliminarlos.